# asp.net core pass linq lambda to view

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I'm using `asp.net core`, when I pass `linq lambda query` to view I get this error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into 
the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType7`1[System.Int64]]',
but this ViewDataDictionary instance 
requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[HRMS.Salaries]'.
```

This my query:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
  var salary = (from salaries in _context.Salaries select new { salaries.Id });
  return View(await salary.ToListAsync());
}
```

and in the view I use:

```
@model IEnumerable<HRMS.Salaries>

  @foreach (var item in Model)
  {
    <tr>
       <td>@item.Id</td> 
    </tr>
  }
```

Comment: You are selecting id, but your view is expectiong Salary itself

Comment: Agree with @AdilMammadov. Try `var salary = _context.Salaries;`

Comment: I agree with @AdilMammadov - To expand: You are currently only selecting a `IEnumerable<int>` (if the `Id` is an `int`) and passing it to your View. You will either need to only select the `Salaries` from your query, and pass them to your view; or you will need to change your `@model` in your View to be `@model IEnumerable<int>`, and display your `foreach` loop with just `<td>@item</td>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason you create an object in your query? If no, try this instead :

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var salary = (from salaries in _context.Salaries
                          select salaries.Id
                      );
            return View(await salary.ToListAsync());
        }
```

Then in your view :

```
@model IEnumerable<int>

                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@item</td> 
                        </tr>
                    }
```

---

Else, if you need the object, use in your query :

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
            {
                var salary = (from salaries in _context.Salaries
                              select salaries
                          );
                return View(await salary.ToListAsync());
            }
```

And keep your view the same :

```
@model IEnumerable<HRMS.Salaries>

                        @foreach (var item in Model)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>@item.Id</td> 
                            </tr>
                        }
```

---

**EDIT** : If you want to pass multiple fields to your View, it's better to use a new object. For this, create a class (for exemple, *SalaryDetailsViewModel*) with the required fields. Then in your controller :

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var salary = (from salaries in _context.Salaries
                          select new SalaryDetailsViewModel { 
                              Id = salaries.Id,
                              Amount = salaries.Amount,
                              Date = salaries.Date,
                              JobTitle = salaries.JobTitle.Name }
                      );
            return View(await salary.ToListAsync());
        }
```

Then adjust your View to call the different fields of your custom object, for display purpose, for example :

```
@model IEnumerable<SalaryDetailsViewModel>

                        @foreach (var item in Model)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>@item.Id</td>
                                <td>@item.Amount</td>
                                <td>@item.Date</td>
                                <td>@item.JobTitle</td>
                            </tr>
                        }
```

Comment: thanks is working when i use  select salaries , but what if i have like this select new { salaries.Id,salaries.Amount,salaries.Date,jobTitle.Name }

Comment: See my edit (it may needs some adjustments, due to the fact I don't know the structure of your class Salary).